# Excel Syntax Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't find the syntax error in the following Excel formula:

I have data in K7:M11 in three sheets namely s_core1,s_core2,s_core3.
The search keys are in A6:C6, A7:B7 and so on.
If A6 is core1, the data in sheet s_core1 should be used to lookup.
If it is core2, the data in sheet s_core2 should be used to lookup.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!"&"$K$11:$M$11"),MATCH(C6,INDIRECT("K"&MATCH(B6,INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!$J$7:$J$9"),0)+6&":M"&MATCH(B6,INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!$J$7:$J$9"),0)+6),0))
```

Please help me with that.

Here is the source for reference if needed:

Please refer the attached excel file in the forum:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/868258-look-up-in-different-sheets.html?p=2968043#post2968043

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The syntax looks okay, but can't see the sheet so not sure what is going on. One thing that will cause an error is if any of your `MATCH` formulas can't find a matching element, resulting in an `#N/A` which will then cause your `INDIRECT` functions to fail. Try stepping through the formula with Evaulate Formula in Excel 2007, look under the Formula menu and click Evaluate Formula). Chances are you'll see an error pop up somewhere, and then you should be able to see what is causing it.

Comment: thank you... is there anyway I can send you the file?

Comment: I've seen others do it with a public Dropbox account, so that may work.

Comment: http://www.ziddu.com/download/20607393/trial22.xls.html

Can you download and view the file from here?

Comment: Looks like it is due to your last `MATCH` formula trying to match a value that is not found in your `K7:M9` matrix. In order for it to work, you'll need to mess around a bit with the `match_type` parameter in your function to allow it to accept values that aren't equal to the one you're seeking. Happy to help later on if you need it :)

Comment: The value to be matched is in second sheet.. I still can't figure how to reference that value in this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't referring to the sheet in the second INDIRECT function - add the bolded part in place of **"K"**

=INDEX(INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!"&"$K$11:$M$11"),MATCH(C6,INDIRECT(**"s_"&A6&"!K"**&MATCH(B6,INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!$J$7:$J$9"),0)+6&":M"&MATCH(B6,INDIRECT("s_"&A6&"!$J$7:$J$9"),0)+6),0))

Comment: Thank you so much @barry... cha, didn't notice it at all... have been struggling for 4 hours.. Thanks again...

Comment: When dealing with large functions and having to debug them, I find that using F9 is very helpful to calculate intermediary values and check if they are what I intend them to be. When you select part of a formula and press F9, Excel will replace that expression with the value it evaluates to. Just a quick tip.